# Когда слово "божий" пишем с большой, а когда с маленькой буквы?

Tags: орфография, значение-слов, семантика, прописная-строчная, прилагательные

У Розенталя ("Справочник по русскому языку: правописание, произношение, литературное редактирование", 2010) сказано, что "с прописной буквы пишутся все прилагательные, образованные от слова *Бог*, например: благодать Божия, Божественная Троица, Божественная литература". При этом указано примечание: "Но в переносном значении: божественный вечер, божия коровка". Так вот, следует ли всегда считать, что во всех словосочетаниях с непрямым значением слово "божий" должно писаться со строчной? Как то:

- искра божья (предрасположенность к добродетели у человека);
- божий воин (ярый христианин, независимо от рода деятельности);
- ему всё божья роса (ему всё безразлично);
- божий одуванчик (тихий, беззащитный, дряхлый человек);
- божья овечка / овца божья (неиспорченный верующий человек, чаще всего женщина) и пр.?

Впрочем, верно ли тогда, что "божий" следует писать со строчной и в таких словосочетаниях, как слово божье (учение Господа), дом божий (церковь), невесты божьи (монахини), ведь здесь также имеется переносный смысл? Однако их почти всегда пишут с прописной... Или же есть какие-то нюансы/традиции написания во всех упомянутых случаях?

Comment: В сочетаниях "слово Божье", "дом Божий" и "невесты Божьи" прилагательное используется в прямом значении.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему. На мой взгляд, тут точно так же переносный смысл. Но почему тогда пишется с прописной?.. Вот и думал, что есть устоявшиеся исключения.

Comment: есть ваш взгляд, а есть учение Церкви, из которого эти словосочетания и перекочевали в светскую речь. Чтобы не превращать филологический форум в теологический, я не стал расписывать значения этих словосочетаний. Просто пояснил для сведения.

Comment: А почему "невесты Божьи" — прямое значение, а "воины божьи" — переносное? На что ориентироваться-то в таких случаях? Может, какие-то развёрнутые статьи есть на эту тему (Божий/божий)?

Comment: я таких статей не знаю.

Comment: Тогда в каждом отдельном случае надо смотреть, а что устоялось — запоминать написание?

Comment: Да, смотреть по Нацкорпусу. Ориентироваться на написание после 90-х, поскольку в СССР "Бог" и связанные с этим словом прилагательные почти всегда писались со строчной.